# TCL: return dynamic TCL to Java programme to write into file

Tags: java, tcl

I am calling a TCL script from Java, in which I dynamically create TCL, like this:

```
 puts " # generated comment"
 puts " set myDict \[dict replace \$otherDict \\"

 foreach {key value} [dict get $abcDict] {
      puts "$key $value"
      ;# here, more TCL is generated
 }
 puts " \]"
```

I basically compare a bunch of dicts and use `puts` to output the differences and similarities between them and thereby create a TCL procedure.

Right now, this gets displayed in my Eclipse console. How can I return the entire generated TCL to Java to write it into a file? I want to create a file that contains the dynamically created TCL procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`puts` command](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/puts.htm) writes strings to channels. It defaults to writing to the `stdout` channel, which goes to the console (or to the parent process, or any number of other things depending on how the tclsh program was called) but if you explicitly say which channel to write to, it writes to that instead. You say using an optional argument which goes *before* the string to write (but after the `-nonewline` option if you are using that).

Where do we get the channel to write to write a file? From the [`open` command](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/open.htm):

```tcl
set theChannel [open "myFile.tcl" w]
```

Note that we've used the `w` mode here as we're going to ***w***rite to the file. The rest of your code can then be written like this:

```tcl
puts $theChannel " # generated comment"
puts $theChannel " set myDict \[dict replace \$otherDict \\"

foreach {key value} [dict get $abcDict] {
    puts $theChannel "$key $value"
    # here, more TCL is generated
}
puts $theChannel " \]"
```

Don't forget to [`close $theChannel`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/close.htm) once you're done with it.

---

Protip: If you're generating code, the [`list` command](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/list.htm) can be *hugely* useful as it does exactly the right sort of quoting that you need for all sorts of things, and is defined to work exactly that way.